# ActiveRecord Postgres adapter generating invalid SQL WHERE clause: WHERE("fieldname")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

ActiveRecord 4.1.1 is generating some peculiar SQL on save that postgres is choking on:

```
SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "uid"
```

I'm pretty sure that the "boolean" being referred to here is actually the `WHERE()` syntax which is expecting a boolean expression as an argument.

`uid` is defined as the primary key on my model (see below)... but why is it just saying `WHERE('uid')` when it's doing select_all (see stacktrace)? (and why is it doing select_all on save?)

### Rails Console

```
p = Project.new(name: "test", description: "test", workflow_id: 1)
=> #<Project name: "test", description: "test", user_id: nil, uid: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, workflow_id: 1, active: nil>
irb(main):031:0> p.save
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
  Project Load (5.5ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "uid"
LINE 1: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
                                                     ^
: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
   (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "uid"
LINE 1: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
                                                     ^
: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('uid') LIMIT 1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:815:in `async_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:815:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:815:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:947:in `select'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:31:in `select_all'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:69:in `select_all'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:603:in `exec_queries'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:487:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:231:in `to_a'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:451:in `find_take'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:98:in `take'
... 41 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    from (irb):31
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>
```

### Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = "uid"

end
```

### ActiveRecord mixin for generating IDs

```
module ActiveRecordUIDExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def generate_uid
      return unless self.class.column_names.include?("uid")
      self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(36**10).to_s(36)
      while !self.class.find_by(:uid, self.id).nil? do
       self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(36**10).to_s(36)
      end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordUIDExtension)
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:before_create, :generate_uid)
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
activerecord (4.1.1)
  activemodel (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  arel (~> 5.0.0)
```

Comment: Your guess about the error is correct; observe: `SELECT 1 WHERE ('uid');` produces `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "uid"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mixin doesn't make any sense. This part right here is causing the bad SQL:

```
self.class.find_by(:uid, self.id)
```

That's producing invalid SQL because you're telling it to. [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) has a flexible interface so it has to do some parsing to see how you're calling it. When you say:

```
find_by(a, b)
```

the argument parsing probably assumes that you're trying to use this form:

```
find_by('some_sql_snippet', placeholder_valid)
```

as in this example from the docs:

```
find_by("published_at < ?", 2.weeks.ago)
```

Then it will probably `to_s` the first argument and scan it for placeholders. When you say:

```
find_by(:uid, self.id)
```

you'll end up with `:uid.to_s` and `self.id` will be ignored because there aren't placeholders in that string. That would explain why you're seeing `where ('uid')` in the SQL.

Fix your mixin to make sense:

```
self.class.find_by(:uid => self.id)
```

or better, switch to `exists?` to avoid building a whole model instance just to see if there's a row in the database:

```
self.class.where(:uid => self.id).exists?
self.class.exists?(:uid => self.id)
```

Comment: Aha! Some old Rails 2 code that didn't make the jump to 4 (and that mysql didn't choke on)! Many thanks for the catch!